# Remove Glyphicons from Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-5.4, glyphicons

I have [laravel-5.4](/questions/tagged/laravel-5.4) project and I want to remove Glyphicons from it. I have tried the following command from my project's root folder:

```
npm uninstall glyphicons-halflings
```

Then I run `npm run production`. However, there is nothing happened and Glyphicons font remains as it is. How could I remove that font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glyphicons is included in bootstrap-sass that is installed through npm.
so If you want to remove the glyphicons you would have to remove the require('boostrap-sass') at your bootstrap.js file.

Or if you really want to remove only the fonts then you remove the

> node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap

directory but this will probably show an error that is glyphicons is not located.

To fix the error above you should go to

> node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss

file and remove this code

```
@import "bootstrap/glyphicons";
```

The problem with this solution is probably after you have done all those stuffs and you update your dependencies using npm run update then all the things you have deleted will be updated to the latest bootstrap-sass dependency unless you have removed bootstrap-sass dependency in your package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
  },
```

Comment: Very good, so, is there any alternative package for bootstrap-sass that uses font awesome instead of glyphicons, so I install it?

Comment: sorry but I can't seem to find a package like that.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy bootstrap definition to your resources folder:

```
mix.copy('node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss', 'resources/assets/sass/_bootstrap.scss');
```

and edit this file by remove or comment elements you don’t want and change all path, for examples to fonts:

`resources/assets/sass/_bootstrap.scss`:

```
// Reset and dependencies
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/normalize";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/print";
// @import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/glyphicons";
```

Ofc you need add this file in place of original bootstrap import `resources/assets/sass/app.scss`:

```
// Bootstrap
// @import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap";
```

After this just run:

```
npm run dev
```

Comment: This is more accurate answer, However the `resources/assets/sass/_bootstrap.scss` is overwritten everytime we run the `npm run dev`